# Plot the impact for each variable in linear regression?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I want to create a plot like below for a lm model calculated using R.

[image]

Is there a simple way of doing it?

The plot above was collected [here in this page](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/identifying-important-independent-variables/).

Comment: good question and after looking at the answers, I'm wondering if anyone has a broom/ggplot2 method for creating a graph, if you want something more customizable

Comment: @hachiko my answer _is_ a ggplot method. The function outputs a fully customisable ggplot object.

Comment: @AllanCameron yes I see that I don't know what I was talking about your code was almost too advanced for me to recognize it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ended up using `relaimpo` package and showing with ggplot answered by @Allan Cameron

```
library(relaimpo)

relative_importance <- calc.relimp(mymodel, type="lmg")$lmg

df = data.frame(
variable=names(relative_importance),
importance=round(c(relative_importance) * 100,2)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(variable, -importance), y = importance)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=importance), vjust=.3, hjust=1.2, size=3, color="white")+
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Relative importance of variables") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

Answer (score 5):

Package {caret} offers a convenient method `varImp`:
Example:

```
library(caret)
my_model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data = mtcars)

## > varImp(my_model)
##
##       Overall
## disp 2.006696
## cyl  2.229809
```

For different measures of variable importance see `?varImp`. Feed values into your plotting library of choice.

Extra: {[ggstatsplot](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/index.html)} calculates *and* plots a host of model stats for a plethora of model objects. This includes [hypotheses about regression coefficients](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/index.html#hypothesis-about-regression-coefficients), for which method [`ggcoefstats()`](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/ggcoefstats.html) might serve your purpose (remember to scale predictor variables for meaningful comparison of coefficients though).

Answer (score 3):

Following the method in the linked article (relative marginal increase in r squared), you could write your own function that takes a formula, and the data frame, then plots the relative importance:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_importance <- function(formula, data) {
  
  lhs <- as.character(as.list(formula)[[2]])
  rhs <- as.list(as.list(formula)[[3]])
  vars <- grep("[+\\*]", rapply(rhs, as.character), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(vars), function(i) {
    f1 <- as.formula(paste(lhs, paste(vars[-i], collapse = "+"), sep = "~"))
    f2 <- as.formula(paste(lhs, paste(c(vars[-i], vars[i]), collapse = "+"), 
                           sep = "~"))
    r1 <- summary(lm(f1, data = data))$r.squared
    r2 <- summary(lm(f2, data = data))$r.squared
    
    data.frame(variable = vars[i], importance = r2 - r1)
  }))
  
  df$importance <- df$importance / sum(df$importance)
  df$variable <- reorder(factor(df$variable), -df$importance)

  ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = importance)) +
    geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "Relative importance of variables",
         subtitle = deparse(formula)) +
    theme_classic(base_size = 16)
}
```

We can test this out with the sample data provided in the linked article:

```
IV <- read.csv(paste0("https://statisticsbyjim.com/wp-content/uploads/",
                      "2017/07/ImportantVariables.csv"))

plot_importance(Strength ~ Time + Pressure + Temperature, data = IV)
```

[image]

And we see that the plot is the same.

We can also test it out on some built-in datasets to demonstrate that its use is generalized:

```r
plot_importance(mpg ~ disp + wt + gear, data = mtcars)
```

[image]

```r
plot_importance(Petal.Length ~ Species + Petal.Width, data = iris)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: you could probably extract the formula terms a bit easier using `terms` or `all.vars`